# C#: Error on Shutdown of Socket?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am trying to dispose of a console application, one part of disposing this is shutting down the server socket, but when I try I get a SocketException and I'm unsure why?

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'A request to send or receive data
>   was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending
>   on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied'

I dispose of the class here, by calling Socket.Shutdown, which is where the error gets thrown.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_serverSocket == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _serverSocket.Close();
    _serverSocket.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: The error message seems painfully clear to me. What are you having trouble understanding? As the message says, the socket has already been disconnected, so the call to `Shutdown()` is not legal. Without a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say how you got yourself into that situation, but regardless it doesn't seem like you need anything other than to check your code and decide whether you even really should be calling `Shutdown()` here.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `_serverSocket` to `null` after disposing, to protect against disposing twice?  Ideally use `Interlocked.Exchange()` for thread safety.  But beyond that we need to see more of your class to help because it seems there might be some other code path that results in the socket getting shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
_serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _serverSocket.Close();
```

already drop connection, so that you don't need `_serverSocket.Dispose();` anymore